# Change e-mail address of Stack Exchange OpenID account

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

How can I change the e-mail address of my Stack Exchange OpenID account?

Unfortunately I can't find such an option anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

You can Login and Manage your OpenId information on [StackExchange's OpenId page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But there's nothing about an e-mail address.

Comment: Agreed. This is not a good answer.